# How to load a database of countries in a web application

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am new to web application development, so sorry in advance if this question is too basic.

The following are the details of the question:

A] Platform being used -- 
 google app engine with python, django.

B] Tutorial link being used -- http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/djangoforms.html

C] Question: In the application i am building, there is a drop down box which allows the user to select their country. Since the list of countries is above 200, i want to construct a database of the countries before the application loads.

Once this application is deployed, i dont want the database to get re-loaded again, since the entries are constant for all the users. How does one achieve this ?

thanks,
Lance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the countries as a constant list:

```
COUNTRIES=['United States', 'England'...]
```

In your model:

```
country=db.StringProperty(verbose_name='Country',required=False, choices=set(COUNTRIES))
```

Now when you load your model form the select will be auto-populated from your countries list.

Comment: thank you, i can see that this will work. But this will load the countries every time a user invokes the application. Is there a way where a database can be loaded and be ready for the application to use when the application starts up.

Comment: If you store the variables in a python list they will not be stored in the database and thus be ready for the application to use when it starts up.  The list will load once and always be available for your application.  Are you trying to hard code the values into your html?

Comment: @lance_klusener Loading the countries from the source code each time an instance is spun up is going to be orders of magnitude quicker than loading them from the datastore every time a page is rendered.

Comment: Thanks Nick for the explanation, i have followed this advice and have put the list of countries in the python code.

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
<select>
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Thanks
Jean

Comment: Jean, in the working version i have: <form action="/UserReporting" name="addCountry" id="addCountry" method="post" >
  <p>Select country: </p>

     <select name="country" id="country">
      <option value="0">Country...</option>
   <option value=1>Afghanistan</option>
   <option value=2>&Aring;land&nbsp;Islands</option>
   <option value=3>Albania</option>
   <option value=4>Algeria</option>
   <option value=5>American&nbsp;Samoa</option>

Comment: Sorry the previous edit went to quick, I have the <select> in my html file with the options for the countries. In the python code however, the optino value comes in, but not the string content of the countries.

Comment: IF you are dead-set in doing it this way what you need to do is put the country string as the options value (ie <option value='Afghanistan'>Afghanistan</option>)

Comment: I did get this working, but decided to use the answer given earlier by @user589983. The reasons being, this reduced the amount of logic in the html code, it also allowed me to use django forms which are easier to work with. This know-how is good to have for the future, so thank you :)